# Azure Filestore & Backup

Tags: azure, backup

I have a physical server that holds documents customer orders in XML and their resultant orders PDF. The locations are mapped from the application server that generates them and the desktops that need to access them via drive mapping.

These files need to be kept for a number of years for regulatory purposes, the current file server needs expanding. So I was thinking that as this data will grow to about 5-8tb over time as the data needs to be held for approx 10 years, then it can be removed.

I could create a VM in Azure with the appropriate storage and then I presume to use MARS to create a backup strategy as if this was an onsight server. But to meet the disk sizing I need a large server as the processing of the server does not need to be very much its just storage.

So I would need to still be able to map the server and desktops to the drive where the files are stored

So I was wondering if anyone could suggest an approach. The data from the desktop would need to be available for the application to access for up to 18 months. So the old data could be archived but still needs to be backed up as retrieval of archive data would be via a manual search.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic for StackOverflow: it's very broad with many potential solutions. Plus, it's not a programming question. That said: Documentation is readily available for Virtual Machines and attached storage (which is durable, blob-backed), as well as Azure File shares and direct blob storage (including archive blobs). How you implement this is really up to you though...

Answer (score 0):

You can map the [Azure file storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) as a network drive on your desktop and then you can take a backup of files stored in Azure file storage for long-term retention.

Azure Backup for Files is in Limited Preview today. It enables you to take scheduled copies of yourFiles and can be managed from the Recovery Services Vault. If you are interested in signing up for this preview, you can drop in a mail with their subscription ID(s) to AskAzureBackupTeam@microsoft.com